# How do I make my Eggbot designs look right on an egg? (Or: how to transform projected plane so shapes look good on a spheroid?)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, spheres, projection

I think my question, in short, is the following: Imagine an spheroid, so with two diameters, and a plane "wrapped" around the spheroid using equirectangular projection. Let the two diameters be equal (so, a sphere), and then draw a circle on the spheroid. Look at the circle from above - it looks circular. If the two diameters are not equal, how do I need to transform the plane such that the circle looks correct again, as best as possible?

Here is more detail on the situation, so you can tell if I'm actually asking the right question :-) I also may have misused maths (I'm British, so "maths") terminology - please tell me if so.

I have an [Eggbot](http://egg-bot.com/). It prints (or rather, plots) flat designs on spherical objects, and also on eggs - i.e. ellipsoids. If you print a design with a circle in it on a spherical object, it looks like a circle. If you print it on an egg, it looks distorted. (Due to the design of the Eggbot, it assumes ellipsoid objects like eggs are spheroids rather than oblate spheroids, and we can do that for this question.)

To compensate for this, it seems like the Eggbot community has a rule of thumb that you stretch designs horizontally by 150% when printing on eggs. But eggs vary, or at least the ones I have do - some are quite round, some are long and thin. So I'd like a more precise answer to the question: how much do I have to stretch my design to get it to look as right as possible on a particular egg?

Eggbot designs are done in Inkscape, using 3200 px wide x 800 px high canvases, and are plotted at 1px per motor stepping in both directions. See [the Eggbot coordinate system](http://wiki.evilmadscientist.com/The_Eggbot_coordinate_system) for existing documentation. The Eggbot takes designs and plots them using an [equirectangular projection](http://wiki.evilmadscientist.com/Eggbot_Quality_Troubleshooting#Map_Projection) - that link has a good picture of what a circle looks like drawn on a sphere and on an egg, and the poor look of the sphere on the egg is the "problem" I want to solve a bit more rigorously.

What I'm hoping for is a formula which takes two inputs - the two diameters of the egg - and outputs a percentage between 100% and 200% which is the y-axis scaling factor that I need to use to make the design look best on that particular egg.

Please let me know if more info is necessary. I'm new here, so apologies for any lapses in etiquette, and thank you for your consideration :-)

**Update**: Thanks for the initial feedback. Yes, the principal axes of the ellipsoid are the coordinate axes. The Eggbot spins the egg around its long axis, and then moves a pen up and down the length of the same axis, thereby giving access to most points on the egg.

The circle I want to look good is a circle centred in the middle of the long axis, with a radius such that the whole circle is visible from one side. [This link](http://wiki.evilmadscientist.com/Eggbot_Quality_Troubleshooting#Map_Projection) has a good picture of what I mean.

I think we could start with "looking like a circle" meaning lying on a plane crossing the ellipsoid, yes.

Comment: Dear Gervase: There are several things that you have left undefined in your question. One is the meaning of the "equirectangular projection" for an  ellipsoid. If it were a sphere, the meaning would be "polar coordinates". One can attempt the same for an ellipsoid, but then you would need to prescribe the location of the coordinate axes. I assume you would use the principal axes of the ellipsoid, but you have to make it clear. Second: There are many circles on the plane. Do you mean an arbitrary circle or you have some restrictions such as center and the radius?

Comment: The last issue is the most delicate: What does it mean to "look like a circle"? For instance, do you want it to lie on a plane (crossing the ellipsoid)? For a planar curve one way to measure the deviation from a circle is to look at the ratio of the circumradius over the inradius and aim to make it as close to 1 as possible. For a non-planar curve one would aim for something more complex. (Right now I am just trying to help you to formulate a mathematically meaningful question.)

Comment: One more thing: If you take a random circle on the plane and apply the spherical coordinates to it to map it to a round sphere (I should have said "spherical" instead of "polar" above), the result will not be a round circle. Thus, I am sure you have some restrictions on your circles (if they really are circles) and you have to figure out what they are. "It is hard to find a black cat in a dark room, especially if you are looking for a white dog".

Comment: You might look at [Easter problem - egg shapes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/125959/6094), which will lead to other relevant postings.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I've added more detail. Thank you for your rigour :-) If anything else is missing, please feel free to make assumptions.